# Get brightness of a picture

Tags: linux, open-source, images, image-processing, command-line

I use [openHAB](http://www.openhab.org/) and want to use an old mobile phone as an day/night indicator. I have installed a webcam app and it is filming the sky.

I can get the latest shot via `http://[ip]/shot.jpg`. Can I get a "brightness value" like this: `curl http://[ip]/shot.jpg | some-command --get-brightness`?

Comment: I'd take a look at the imagemagick package, see e.g.: [Detect image's overall brightness](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11304&sid=0aa9764bcd32c1718d2a0c280acd4d71) // [How to determine if image is dark? (high contrast, low brightness)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7935814/2533433) // [Quickly get brightness / lumanacity of images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8745670/2533433)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Use imagemagick to check the brightness of the image will work as long as the phone camera does not have auto-exposure or it is turned off, otherwise it will only work for extreme values, (dark/light), e.g. `convert <image> -colorspace Gray -format "%[fx:quantumrange*image.mean]" info:`
2. exiftool can parse the EXIF information from the file and extract the "Light Value" which should give you a reasonably consistent reading, *(assuming that the camera on your specific phone includes this tag)*.

Both tools are free, gratis & open source and available for most platforms.

Comment: I just tested the `convert` command, it works and returns a number like 6310.78 or 13553.1

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - so now all you have to do is calibrate your values for the camera and the view that it has.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu/Debian package `graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat` enough?

Comment: @Motte001 - I think last time I just used `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`.